# Change the default namespace of a VSTO project

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

Is it possible to change the default namespace of a VSTO project?... I've tried opening the project file in notepad and changing the `rootnamespace` xml param to my new desired name, but it fails to load the add-in when Word starts. It throws a generic runtime error. I suspect that the manifest still points to the previous namespace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Officially", [you cannot change the default namespace of a VSTO project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268744.aspx). But there is a way, by editing the project file and doing some find&replace. [This blog post](http://trashvin.blogspot.com/2007/12/renaming-default-namespaces-for-vsto.html) explains how to do it.

Comment: Just spent two hours fixing all of the problems caused by this solution.

Comment: @Eric care to share an answer with what steps you took to fix the problems caused (or a caution of what problems are caused?) or did you have to undo instead of fix?

Comment: I had to undo instead of fix.